# Installing redis-server-stack on MacOsx (load command 0x80000034 is unknown) error

Tags: redis

I have `redis-server` running fine. I cant run `redis-server-stack`. The modules don't seem to be loading.

```
41188:M 21 Oct 2023 16:35:10.184 # Module /usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so failed to load: dlopen(/usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so: cannot load 'redisearch.so' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so: stat() failed with errno=1


go version go1.21.3 darwin/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Timeline_of_releases) means at best OS X 10.15 ([Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina)) from 2019, on Intel-based CPU (hence the use of `darwin/amd64` instead of arm64 for M1 or M2 Apple silicon).
So the OS itself might be a bit old, depending on the version of

As mentioned in the [RediSearch README](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch):

> The [Redis Stack Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack-server/) makes it easy to try RediSearch.

I would first try that image, using Docker, to check if the same feature is easier to use than a local installation.

Comment: Why doesnt redis-server load the modules that are there? I am not a user of docker.  I had redis-server-stack working.  I upgrade everything broke. Redis standalone works fine.. I just cant load modules after upgrade.. The brew casks for Redis dont show verison to downgrade to previous working setup.

Comment: @Merlin Not sure, which is why I recommended using a Docker image (inside which every element of the stack is compatible). What MacOS version are you using?

Comment: Mohave.. need 32bit OS for another program.

Comment: @Merlin You mean [Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave), macOS 10.14 I suppose? I would try, for testing, a VM (VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop) to see if that work better with a more recent version of macOS, since the crux of my answer is that the error could be the result of a kernel incompatibility (too old).

Comment: I had to rebuild a 2nd Mac box... The server works, but now need a VM for 32bit program.